# Check if the result is an Undefined variable after sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I've made an audio player with a playlist (php, MySql, html5)

It works fine.

When a track is finished, the player automatically loads (with ajax) the next track.

So i have a sql query to know the next track ID (the track list is ordered by date).

It's ok but when the player read the last track, the sql query can't find the next id (because it doesn't exist, there is no track with a date before).

So i want to do this : check if my result is not null, and if it is null, i defined my var with the 1st id.
But it doesn't work. I have always an Undefined variable.

I've tried with 
isset, empty, is_null

Here is my code :

```
$next_id = $bdd->prepare('
SELECT id
FROM site_decouvrir 
WHERE publish = 1 AND date_publication < :date_publication 
ORDER BY date_publication DESC LIMIT 1');

$next_id->execute(array('date_publication' => $date_publication));

while ($donnees_2 = $next_id->fetch())
{
    // This part is ok untill i reach the last track
    if (isset($donnees_2['id'])) {
        $id_next_track = $donnees_2['id'];
    } else {
        // This part is not executed, when $donnees_2['id'] is null
        $id_next_track = $id_premier_morceau;
    }
}
```

Can you give me some advices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop will handle that.  While the statement `$donnees_2 = $next_id->fetch()` is true, as in when a query is successful the loop runs.  Therefore there wil be an `id` param and your if statement will be executed.

When the statement fails the while loop exits and your `else` block is never executed.

If you want to set the param do it after the while loop